# How To Store Value in Global Variable from onChange Function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64

I need to access the returned value from an onChange function, but it's not reading anything cause it's obviously not storing properly. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="UploadBox" className="custom-file-input" id="UploadBox" onChange={this.onChange} />
```

JS:

```
onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedImage: e.target.files[0]
        })

        let files = e.target.files;
        let file = e.target.files[0];

        if (files.length > 0 && file) {
            this.getBase64(files[0]);
        }
    }

    getBase64(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        console.log(file);

        reader.onload = function () {
            console.log(reader.result);
            let binaryString = reader.result;
            let btoaString = btoa(binaryString);
            //console.log(btoaString);
            return binaryString;
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        }
    }
```

Further On Down Here is where I need to store the return value in the imageBase64Function variable:

```
let imageBase64Function = this.getBase64();
```

When I do the console.log of the reader.result, I'm getting the correct base64 information. But I need to store it in the imageBase64 variable. I've tried researching global variables and assignments, but I know I'm doing something wrong. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Edit: Solved after trying to setState and using the base64 string by removing the meta data at the beginning

```
constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedImage: null,
            errors: {}
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.getBase64 = this.getBase64.bind(this);
    }

onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedImage: e.target.files[0]
        })

        let files = e.target.files;
        let file = e.target.files[0];

        if (files.length > 0 && file) {
            this.getBase64(files[0]);
        }
    }

    getBase64(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        console.log(file);

        reader.onload = function () {
            console.log(reader.result);
            let binaryString = reader.result;
            let base64OrigString = binaryString.split('base64,');
            let base64Split = base64OrigString[1];
            //return binaryString;
            this.setState({selectedImage: base64Split})
        }.bind(this)

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of returning `binaryString`, couldn't you call `this.setState({ selectedImage: binaryString })`?

Comment: And then just call this.state.binaryString as the variable? Would that work?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to try it out 

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to be working? I am getting a this.setState is not a function even after I've bound both functions to the state? I've updated my original post to show you what it looks like now.

Comment: Create a testable example using CodeSandbox - codesandbox.io/

Comment: I finally got it to work. I wasn't .bind(this) on the outside curly brackets to make sure it bound it since it was inside the .onload. Thanks for your help. Can you mark your response as an answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: Done. I added another idea possible solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `binaryString`, you can call `this.setState({ selectedImage: binaryString })`. As you discovered in your testing, you needed to un`bind(this)` so that `this.setState` could be called from within your nested function. Another possible solution would be to leave the binding as it was, but change how you call the anonymous `reader.onload` function. That will preserve the outside `this` and allow you to access `this.state` from within the block.

```js
reader.onload = () => { … }
```